# Another equivalent characterization of Schwartz function?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Suppose I have a smooth function $\psi$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$, for which I know that 
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\left||x|^k\Delta^{p}\psi(x)\right|<\infty
$$
for all $k,p\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Is this already sufficient for $\psi$ to be a Schwartz function?

I have tried fooling around with the Fourier transform, the problem seems to be however, that I am not able to control terms of the form
$$
|x|D^p(|x|^{2k}\hat{\psi})
$$
I am quite sure that the solution is pretty elementary, but I cannot figure it...

Comment: Surely yes... Hmm. Seems like the proof that the Fourier transform maps the Schwarz space to itself involves similar problems, getting bounds on $|x|^ND^\alpha f$ from bounds on $D^\alpha(|x|^Nf)$. This is going to be maybe trickier, but I'd start by making sure I understood _that_ argument.